# Cannot push to Heroku main

Tags: sql-server, git, heroku

I'm trying to deploy using Heroku.
When pushing my code to Heroku git through its HTTPS URL, I see an error like this

> **git push heroku main**  fatal: unable to access 'https://projectname.herokuapp.com/': The requested URL returned
> error: 502

I already removed Heroku and added a new Heroku but it still didn't work. Can anyone help me?

done✔✔✔

Comment: `502 Bad Gateway` *can* be a temporary error coming from the site, e.g., if it's overloaded. You'll see these a lot when there's a DDoS attack. See, e.g., https://www.itpro.com/web-hosting/30258/what-is-a-502-bad-gateway-and-how-do-you-fix-it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use the address where your app is *hosted* as a Git remote:

```
https://mfal-project.herokuapp.com/
```

But the address where your app is hosted and the address its Git service uses are different.

Instead of adding the remote manually, I suggest you remove the existing one using `git remote rm heroku` and then ask [the Heroku CLI to add a remote for you](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-git-remote):

```
heroku git:remote -a mfal-project
```

You should now see a new remote called `heroku` that looks more like

```
https://git.heroku.com/mfal-project.git
```